# Uiautomatorviewer.bat removed from Android SDK?

Tags: android, uiautomatorviewer

I wanted to use the `uiautomatorviewer.bat` today, but when I clicked on it, it removed itself. This typically happens when there is an update to the file and somehow Android Studio recognizes this. Is the `layout inspector` now the replacement for the `uiautomatorviewer`? Since the documentation still mentions the tool, e.g.
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator, I am not sure.
There are still several versions of the `uiautomator.jar` shipped with the Android-SDK,
e.g. in `Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\` and in `Android\Sdk\tools\lib\` for instance.
But of course, you can't directly invoke the JAR file, as certain dependencies (paths) are missing. I tried to use some old `uiautomatorviewer.bat`, but can't place it into `Android\Sdk\tools\bin\` due to permission issues. Adjusting the paths would be a mess.
I'd like to use `uiautomatorviewer` over the `layout inspector` due to certain information, which I couldn't locate in the output of the `layout inspector`.

OS: Windows 10 
Android Studio: 4.2.2 including the latest SDK tools.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `uiautomatorviewer.bat` isn't available anymore in the latest Android SDKs, I have created my own version of it:

```
@echo off

rem don't modify the caller's environment
setlocal

set prog_dir=E:\Android\Android\Sdk\tools
rem depends on your environment, either x86_64 or x86
set swt_path=E:\Android\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64
set frameworkdir=E:\Android\Android\Sdk\tools\lib
set jarfile=uiautomatorviewer-26.0.0-dev.jar
set jarpath=%frameworkdir%\%jarfile%

rem we need to use Java8 otherwise the option -Djava.ext.dirs= is not available anymore
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe

set javaextdirs=%swt_path%;%frameworkdir%

call "%java_exe%" "-Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs%" "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=%prog_dir%" -jar %jarpath% %*
```

You just need to adjust the paths accordingly. An even better approach would be to refactor the script using the env variable `ANDROID_HOME`. Note: You **can't use** any **java version > 1.8**, because the option `-Djava.ext.dirs` is not supported anymore in those versions.

Answer (score 0):

In my setup I was needed to add some changes to [@auermich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110448/auermich) .bat
The problem was in usage of Program Files as home for Android SDK

```
@echo off

setlocal

set prog_dir=C:\Program Files\Android\androidSdkWindows\tools
set swt_path=C:\Program Files\Android\androidSdkWindows\tools\lib\x86_64
set frameworkdir=C:\Program Files\Android\androidSdkWindows\tools\lib
set jarpath="C:\Program Files\Android\androidSdkWindows\tools\lib\uiautomatorviewer-26.0.0-dev.jar"
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe
set javaextdirs=%swt_path%;%frameworkdir%

call "%java_exe%" "-Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs%" "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=%prog_dir%" -jar %jarpath% %*
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for Java > 1.8 (tested with Java 11).

```bash
@echo off

setlocal

set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1"
set "ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
set "TOOLS_DIR=%ANDROID_HOME%\tools"
set "LIB_DIR=%TOOLS_DIR%\lib"

rem Set classpath
set "CLASSPATH=%LIB_DIR%\uiautomatorviewer-26.0.0-dev.jar;%LIB_DIR%\x86_64\swt.jar;%ANDROID_HOME%\cmdline-tools\latest\lib\common\tools.common.jar;%LIB_DIR%\ddmlib-26.0.0-dev.jar"

rem Launch UiAutomatorViewer
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Xmx512m -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools" com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer %*

endlocal
```

Note: [auermich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110448/auermich)'s code still works for me if I point to my JRE folder (1.8) instead of JDK (11).