# Where is uiautomator.bat

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded the latest Android Studio with the latest Android SDK on a Windows machine. I go to the SDK directory and there is no tools directory and when I search the SDK directory for uiautomator.bat I get no results. I did delete the SDK and reinstalled it and there was still no UIAutomatorViewer. Where is this tool located? If it has been deprecated that's fine, what can I use instead?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68365619/uiautomatorviewer-bat-removed-from-android-sdk) it seems that it was depreciated. (however you may find some luck by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75631434/15749574))

As a replacement, you can use the [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector). it allows you to inspect your app's layout hierarchy, view layout bounds. You can access it from the View --> Tool Windows -> Layout Inspector menu in Android Studio (if I recall correctly)

however, if you need to automate the ui interactions for testing purposes I would recommend using [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso)

Comment: So, I started the Layout inspector, and it saw my device isn't connecting though. I have a Google Pixel 8 Pro. All I see is a blank screen in the layout inspector and in the component tree it says "Waiting for Layout Inspector to connect". It sees my device in the devices dropdown and I have my phone selected. It just isn't connecting for some reason

Comment: fairly common issue, there are many posts and reasons why this may occur, make sure the app you want to inspect is debuggable and try to maybe restart android studio

Comment: It looks like I can't inspect apps on already on my phone I had to start the default app in Android Studio and then it showed up on my phone. I need to inspect elements of apps installed on my phone for automated testing purposes. I am not developing Android apps I am testing them.  UiAutomatorViewer did that, are there any other tools you suggest for that purpose?

Comment: What exactly do you want to inspect in the app itself? (element sizes, maybe content descriptions ?)

Comment: Ids, accessibility_id, xpath, and other ways to identify the elements in an app.

Comment: well, that might be hard due to obfuscation (talking about ids and accessibility_id, not sure if xpath even exists in android)

Comment: I am watching a course on Udemy that is using UiAutomatorViewer to find Id's , and Xpath. Since that is not available, how does one find elements anymore if there is obfuscation? Sorry for all the questions, I am very new to mobile testing.

Comment: I am not sure why would you reference those IDs in the first place, would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: I would reference IDs, XPath, etc to find the elements with my automation, to do various actions, like tap, send keys, etc.

Comment: Usually the automatic tests are handled by the android dev themselves, that's why I am confused

Comment: unit tests sure, but end-to-end integration tests those are for the tester to do.

Comment: I've written those before, I don't think it's possible for testers to automate the process, cause they won't be able to reference the views in a human way

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. This conversation opened my eyes to what is going on in the mobile app world.

Comment: just to be clear, there are mobile app testers for android, but they usually check things like accessibilty / tracking / functionality (manually)